# Locking database rows

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, locking

I have a table in my database with defined jobs. One of jobs attribute is status, which can be [waiting, in_progress, done]. To process jobs i have defined master-worker relation between two servers, they work in the following way:

1. master looks for the first record in database with status 'waiting' and triggers a worker server to process the job.
2. Triggered worker sets status on the job to 'in_progress' in one transaction and starts executing the job (in the meantime server is looking for next job with status 'waiting' and triggers another worker)
3. when the job is done worker sets status on the job to 'done'

This is the perfect case scenario, however it might happen that during job execution one of the workers dies. In this case job needs to be restarted, however master has no way of verifying if job was done other than checking its status in database ('done'). Therefore if worker dies, in database the job has still status 'in_progress' and server has no idea that worker died and that job needs to be restarted. (we can't get any feedback from worker, we can not ping it and we can not get information what job is he currently working on)

My idea to solve this problem would be:

1. After worker changed job's status to 'in_progress' (transaction committed) he would open a new transaction with lock on the particular job.
2. Master, while looking for jobs to start would look for both 'waiting' and 'in_progress' which are not locked
3. If worker dies, transaction would break, releasing the lock from job record in database and master would reprocess it.

now i'm looking for a way to verify it this would indeed work. Possibly with SQL sctipt in SQL developer (two instances), i would like this to work in the following way:

**Instance 1:**

1. open transaction and create a row lock on row_1
2. sleep for 5 min
3. release lock

**Instance 2:**

1. Open transaction and look for row matching criteria (row_1 and row_2 match criteria)
2. return selected row

then i would kill **instance 1** to simulate worker death and run instance 2 again.

Please advise if my approach is correct

**P.S**
Also could you point me to some good explanation how can i create script form **instance 1**?

Comment: Could it be you try to reinvent the wheel?   Oracle has its own job management built in.  If you want to do it your way, I would let the worker show it's still alive, update a "last_active" column in the job every minute.  If the master notices a time-out, he may consider the worker "dead".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille this timeout solution won't work in my case since it is not possible to alter database schema. Could you briefly explain how built in job management could be used to archive my goal?

Comment: You could always create a schema of your own..  For explanation, see Oracle's excellent documentation http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/DBMSScheduler/DBMSScheduler.htm.

Comment: I have not tested this, but how about something like this. Instead of having a status of "in-progess", simply lock the row, by performing a select ... for update skip locked rows then an update, which sets the status to "done". But do not commit the transaction until the job is complete.

Comment: @BobC this is one idea of the ideas, however im not sure about performance of such solution, since this would hold open transaction for quite a long time, do you know anything about this?

Comment: How long does your job take? How many concurrent jobs are you running? How much (hardware) resource do you have? Which areas of performance are you concerned with?